# Include/exclude files for remote coverage in Codeception

Tags: code-coverage, codeception

I've just been given a legacy project to maintain, and I started by putting it in a test harness (Codeception) and running coverage on it. However, it currently only runs via PHPBrowser (unit testing is currently not possible due to its complexity and legacy nature), so it needs remote coverage. I've tried specifying which files should and shouldn't be covered, but it looks like it's completely ignoring that and including all files, including non-PHP files.

I'm running the tests with `codecept run acceptance --no-colors --coverage-html coverage`.

This is my `codeception.yml` file:

```yaml
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
settings:
    lint: false
coverage:
    enabled: true
    include:
        - api_base/api/web/*
    exclude:
        - api_base/system/config.php
```

And this is `acceptance.yml`:

```yaml
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration
#
# Suite for acceptance tests.
# Perform tests in browser using the WebDriver or PhpBrowser.
# If you need both WebDriver and PHPBrowser tests - create a separate suite.

actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://new-project.local/api/web
        - \Helper\Acceptance
```

The `c3.php` file is in the root of the project. Here's a rough idea of the directory structure:

```
+- api_base/
|   +- api/
|   |   +- web/
|   |   |   \- *.php
|   |   \- *
|   +- README.md
|   +- system/
|   |   +- config.php
|   |   \- *
|   \- *
+- bin/
|   \- *
+- c3.php
+- codeception.yml
+- composer.json
+- composer.lock
+- tests/
|   +- acceptance/
|   |   \- AcceptanceCest.php
|   \- *
\- vendor/
    \- *
```

The files that are in the report have the correct coverage but there are files I don't want included. All files are currently being included, even if I specify `exclude: [ ./*.* ]`. I want most of the PHP files and none of the non-PHP files included in the remote coverage report. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Excluding all files doesn't work because it results in empty list of files and empty list means that the file filter is disabled. I have no idea why you get non-PHP files.

Comment: @Naktibalda Can you explain why `exclude: [ api_base/system/config.php ]` doesn't exclude the file? Can you point me to an example of `include` and `exclude` that works for remote coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Your `exclude` setting doesn't work, because it doesn't overlap with `include`.

PhpCodeCoverage library used to have separate lists - whitelist and blacklist, but blacklist was removed few major versions ago. All `exclude` does now is it removes files from the whitelist and it can't remove the file that has never been in the whitelist.

[Relevant code](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/blob/cd84543b4b968022797b3380a45d2d973c2de9ff/src/Filter.php#L46-L73).

The solution to your problem is to add `api_base/system/` directory to `include` list.

```
coverage:
   enabled: true
   include:
       - api_base/api/web/*
       - api_base/system/*
   exclude:
       - api_base/system/config.php
```

Update 2021-10-10:

To exclude non-PHP files, change include rule to match .php files only:

```
- api_base/api/web/*.php
```

Comment: But why does `include: [ api_base/api/web/* ]` automatically include `api_base/system/config.php` which is outside that structure?

Comment: Disclosure: I have never used include/exclude. If you get unfiltered results, the file list in the filter is still empty. The code in https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/4.1/src/Codeception/Coverage/Filter.php#L169-L172 seems odd to me. Could you try to append one more `/*` to path and see if it makes a difference?        - api_base/api/web/*/*

Comment: No, that made no difference. It seems that all files are being included, and I can then add files to the list. It fails on PHP versions 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3-7.4, & 8.0. I've been using code coverage for years, but this is the first time I've tried remote code coverage.

Comment: To exclude non-php files set include rule to `- api_base/api/web/*.php`